# PHP Oracle Query Data Grouping

Tags: php, sql, oracle

[image]

My query data design in table like this :

```
SHIPMENT_NO     SHIPMENT_DATE   PART_NAME   BOX_NUMBER
DG3-14040001    4/24/2014       TEST        S201551254
DG3-14040001    4/24/2014       TEST        S010101010
DG3-14040001    4/24/2014       TEST        S100200123
DG2-14040001    4/24/2014       DG-M11-A    S001545525
```

What I wanted is :

```
SHIPMENT_NO     SHIPMENT_DATE   PART_NAME   BOX_NUMBER
DG3-14040001    4/24/2014       TEST        S201551254
                4/24/2014       TEST        S010101010
                4/24/2014       TEST        S100200123
DG2-14040001    4/24/2014       DG-M11-A    S001545525
```

Because the shipment no DG3-14040001 same, so it will show just 1 value.

and here is My Oracle SQL :

```
SELECT SHIPMENT_NO, SHIPMENT_DATE, PART_NAME, BOX_NUMBER FROM DIGI_SHIPMENT_SCAN WHERE TO_CHAR(SHIPMENT_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' GROUP BY SHIPMENT_NO, SHIPMENT_DATE, PART_NAME, BOX_NUMBER

while($d1 = oci_fetch_array($result_q1))
{
$shp_no = $d1['SHIPMENT_NO'];
$shp_date = $d1['SHIPMENT_DATE'];
$part_name = $d1['PART_NAME'];
$box_number = $d1['BOX_NUMBER'];

SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_SHP FROM DIGI_SHIPMENT_SCAN WHERE TO_CHAR(SHIPMENT_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' AND SHIPMENT_NO = '$shp_no'
$result_q3 = oci_parse($c1, $q3);
oci_execute($result_q3);

$d3 = oci_fetch_array($result_q3);
$total_shp = $d3['TOTAL_SHP'];

<td class="td_brd7 td_brd6" rowspan="<?php echo $total_shp; ?>"><?php echo $shp_no; ?></td>
<td class="td_brd7 td_brd6" rowspan="<?php echo $total_shp; ?>"><?php echo $shp_date; ?></td>
<td class="td_brd7 td_brd6" rowspan="<?php echo $total_shp; ?>"><?php echo $part_name; ?></td>
<td class="td_brd7 td_brd6" rowspan="<?php echo $total_shp; ?>"><?php echo $box_number; ?></td>
}
```

When the result appears, it will show Double Shipment No depends on the BOX Number total row query.

You can see on the picture, Shipment No should be show 1 value because same value.

Please help to advice.

Comment: this is something you take care of with the application reporting side normally. you might be able to do something like this using cubes, but this should be handled by your reporting solution.

Comment: I agree with PlantTheldea, this is something to  handle programatically on the application side, not as part of a query.  Its so much easier.

Comment: Hi I updated my post into the application side code query. Please read that

Comment: @bDir Updated my answer.  I am anxious to know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of formatting really should be done at the application level, even though it is possible in SQL.  Removing the value from a row of a table makes the result no longer a relational data set.

You can do this with `LAG()`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN SHIPMENT_NO = LAG(SHIPMENT_NO) OVER (ORDER BY SHIPMENT_NO, SHIPMENT_DATE, PART_NAME, BOX_NUMBER) AND
                  SHIPMENT_DATE = LAG(SHIPMENT_DATE) OVER (ORDER BY SHIPMENT_NO, SHIPMENT_DATE, PART_NAME, BOX_NUMBER) AND
                  PART_NAME = LAG(PART_NAME) OVER (ORDER BY SHIPMENT_NO, SHIPMENT_DATE, PART_NAME, BOX_NUMBER) 
             THEN ''
             ELSE SHIPMENT_NO
        END) as SHIPMENT_NO,
       DSS.SHIPMENT_DATE, DSS.PART_NAME, DSS.BOX_NUMBER
FROM DIGI_SHIPMENT_SCAN DSS
WHERE TO_CHAR(SHIPMENT_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'
GROUP BY DSS.SHIPMENT_NO, DSS.SHIPMENT_DATE, DSS.PART_NAME, DSS>BOX_NUMBER
ORDER BY DSS.SHIPMENT_NO, DSS.SHIPMENT_DATE, DSS.PART_NAME, DSS.BOX_NUMBER;
```

Doing so requires handling some subtleties.  The output needs to be explicitly ordered.  You cannot depend on the ordering of a result set unless you include an `order by` clause.  You then need to use the same ordering for the `lag()`, without a `partition by` clause.

Notice that the query also uses table aliases.  This is because the column alias `SHIPMENT_NO` can be confused with the column `DSS.SHIPMENT_NO` in the `order by` clause.  You need to be specific, or all the blank columns will appear together.

Comment: I attached picture example to make my question clear. Please see that

Answer (score 0):

This should normally be done in your application logic, but it can also be done with clever use of the LAG() function.

LAG() allows you to evaluate the previous row according to a certain ordering. You can then apply a CASE WHEN to display NULL when it is the same as the previous row.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm

Example:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LAG(Shipment_No)
     OVER (ORDER BY Shipment_No, Order_Date)  = Shipment_NO
     THEN NULL ELSE Shipment_No END AS Shipment_NO,
    (...)
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY Shipment_No, Order_Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using `break on`?

```
break on SHIPMENT_NO;
SELECT SHIPMENT_NO, SHIPMENT_DATE, PART_NAME, BOX_NUMBER 
FROM DIGI_SHIPMENT_SCAN WHERE 
TO_CHAR(SHIPMENT_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')
BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' GROUP BY
SHIPMENT_NO, SHIPMENT_DATE, PART_NAME, BOX_NUMBER
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch6.htm

Suppressing Duplicate Values in Break Columns

The `BREAK` command suppresses duplicate values by default in the column or expression you name. Thus, to suppress the duplicate values in a column specified in an `ORDER BY` clause, use the `BREAK` command in its simplest form:

```
BREAK ON break_column
```

Note:
Whenever you specify a column or expression in a `BREAK` command, use an `ORDER BY` clause specifying the same column or expression. If you do not do this, breaks occur every time the column value changes.
Example 6-10 Suppressing Duplicate Values in a Break Column

To suppress the display of duplicate department numbers in the query results shown, enter the following commands:

```
BREAK ON DEPARTMENT_ID;
```

For the following query (which is the current query stored in the buffer):

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID, LAST_NAME, SALARY
FROM EMP_DETAILS_VIEW
WHERE SALARY > 12000
ORDER BY DEPARTMENT_ID;
DEPARTMENT_ID LAST_NAME 



               SALARY
------------- ------------------------- ----------
           20 Hartstein                      13000
           80 Russell                        14000
              Partners                       13500
           90 King                           24000
              Kochhar                        17000
              De Haan                        17000

6 rows selected.
```